# node - see what version of package is used during require()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependency-management

I have a node module without a `package.json` (which I'm trying to fix). The package uses `cheerio` and `superagent`:

```
var log = console.log.bind(console),
    superagent = require('superagent'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');
```

These dependencies are pulled in from parent project or from global modules. **How can I tell exactly what version of the package is being loaded?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just require the package.

```
var package = require('supertest/package.json');
console.log(package.version);
```

Comment: i'm not exactly sure what you mean by that.

Comment: You're right sorry, I didn't realise you could require a package (rather than a file) using that syntax. Your answer works perfectly!

Comment: you can require every file inside a package this way. Thats how you can import only parts of modules as well.

Answer (score -1):

`npm list` for local packages or `npm list -g` for globally installed packages.

The result should look like (package@version):
[image]

And you can know the version of package name directly by `npm list <pacakage-name>`

Comment: I know `npm ls`. However npm ls seems to be about what is installed (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) , rather than what will be loaded.

Comment: A quick and easy way is to verify via the package.json file. Why dont you use it ? and verify if the locally nistalled package is what is being loaded.

Comment: I am intending to create a package.json I just want to know what version of the package to depend on first!